# Acer Aspire E15 wireless issue

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10, acer, atheros

Just installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 10, and got a problem. My laptop can't find my Wi-Fi, but it finds another wireless networks without any problems. Kernel version is 4.13.0.16-generic. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What channel is your wifi currently using?

Comment: @Jeremy31 13 and extension channel is 9

Comment: @Jeremy31 oh thanks for the hint changed the channel and it started working